# How to format the <output> of a type range slider?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to format the range slider so the result appear duplicated.
For eg. it returned 16 by default. I want under the slider to see 16x16, 32x32...Both numbers must move togheter.

Heres what i tried:

```
 <input type="range" min="2" max="50" value="16" class="size"
 oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value">
  <output>16</output
```

Is there a way to format the output?
Thank you

Comment: `this.nextElementSibling.value = \`${this.value}x${this.value}\`` - [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) may help?

Comment: Thank you very much, been looking for that for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<input type="range" min="2" max="50" value="16" class="size" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = `${this.value}x${this.value}`"><output></output>
```